# De que modo alterar caminho variável ambiente $HOME para outro?

Tags: linux, variáveis, bash, shell

A intenção é carregar consigo todos arquivos "criados ou baixados", e montá-lo novamente em quaisquer distro LiveCD, deixando-o como diretório padrão.

Note que, o essencial nesta lógica de raciocínio é de apenas **salvar arquivos** criados e vindos da internet, sem qualquer preocupação em salvar as configurações (arquivos ocultos).

Fiz deste modo:

```
$ unset $HOME

$ HOME=/mnt/sda1

$ export HOME

$ echo $HOME

$ /mnt/sda1
```

> No entanto, não consigo gravar ou executar nada ali, recebo a seguinte mensagem - **Read-only file system**
>   Já tentei efetuar a trocar de permissão com o comando - `chmod 777 /mnt/sda1` mas, foi impossível.

Tenho comigo que há algo correlacionado ao nome de *usuário*.

Estou na tentativa de encontrar a solução.

Comment: Observe que o problema pode estar na hora em que a unidade foi montada, você que montou?
para alterar o $HOME, basta você digitar no terminal: export HOME=caminho/novo

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui, pode te ajudar:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write

Comment: Acho q seria mais viável alterar o caminho da pasta do usuário, usando o `usermod`.

Comment: @BrumazziDB Tudo bem, mas o maximo  que consegui fazer com esta ferramenta(`usermod`) foi "inutilizar" grande parte do meu SO.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, você olhou a documentação do comando? o `usermod` serve para alterar a conta do usuário (diretório raiz, validade, grupos, etc).
Não vejo como o comando "initilizaria o SO"